# 3D scanners that captures movement?

Tags: 3d-meshes, 3d-modeling, motion-capture

Could there be a 3D scanner that captures movement? One that scans, let us say, 30 times per second (for 30 fps) to make an animated 3D scene? Is this possible? Why?

Suppose we want to scan a person dancing (I know a similar result could be achieved by applying a 3D scan of the person to a motion-captured data, but it is an example). Instead of a simple 3D scan of the person, it would make 30 scans every second. Then a computer would get all these point clouds data (of each "frame") and merge them into an animation by comparing different scans.
It is different from motion capture because these 3D scans would create many point clouds every second, rather than just capturing the motion by itself. Just like normal cameras film several frames per second to make a video, 3D movement scanners would make several scans to make a 3D animated scene.

Does this already exist? And do you think the limit of nowadays computers processing powers are a problem to scan a scene with such high frequency (30 scans per second)?

Comment: You mean something alike Microsoft Kinect ?

Comment: Kinect sprung to my mind as well. Kinect2 outputs a 512 x 424 depth map, which you can convert into a point cloud. To scan an object from all angles, you could use 3 or more Kinect devices, align the point clouds and merge them, this is a solved problem (http://pointclouds.org/). The scanning won't be a problem as you could just store the depth maps as image sequences, and do the alignment and merging as postprocessing. I don't think real time alignment and merging of the point clouds is feasible, as it is quite a complex procedure, but I could be wrong!

Comment: But isn't Kinect just like motion capture? I thought it just created a skeleton with the movement of the person rather than making a 3D model many times per second. I didn't know that Kinect 2 can make depth maps! Thanks.

Comment: Motion-capture is the capability Microsoft pushes most, since that is most relevant to using the Kinect for controlling games, but it achieves the motion capture by capturing an entire depth image and then analyzing that image for people in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyone having done this but it may be possible. There are a number of 3D scanning systems available that use consumer sensors like Kinect; as you can see in this [video of one such system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbcnRgVNsZk) you move the Kinect around the object and record it from multiple angles, so you could get multiple angles simultaneously by having multiple Kinects.

> do you think the limit of nowadays computers processing powers are a problem to scan a scene with such high frequency

Unless you're trying to generate the animated scan *in real-time* then no processing isn't a limiting factor. While generating a 3D mesh from the scan images is a processing-intensive task, capturing the images is done at the framerate of your camera, and then you process the images later. The main limitations are physical ones, like getting a bunch of Kinects and building the rig to hold them.